# javascript regex extract ONLY 4 or 5 digits numbers except

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this javascript `str.match(regex)`

REgex is

```
/(?!(?:2020|2021)$)\d{4,5}/g
```

Test text

```
12345
R411186062 In 2020 voice nr: 26324 htt ps:// site.com
123456202077
<p style="font-weight: 400;">„Pour Elle“
56542
```

I need extract only 4 or 5 exactly digits from string except numbers 2020 and 2021, but this regex extract part of numbers which have more than 5 digits.

Result:

12345, 41118, 6062, 2020, 26324, 12345, 62020, 56542

[image]
Expected result:
12345, 26324, 56542

How to fix regex?

Comment: What is that `$` doing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use word boundary for that

```
\b\d{4,5}\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/16ebJ7/1

This will give you the expected results

#### EDIT

To exclude 2020 and 2021 you can use a negative look ahead

```
(?!2020|2021)\b\d{4,5}\b
```

Comment: I need extract only 4 or 5 exactly digits from string `except numbers 2020 and 2021`,

Comment: i found new problems :) with such strings `21/09/2020 4204******4816 text MCC-5541 REF: 209686` regex return `4816` part of card number, also be perfect if it possible skip dublicates from match result

Comment: You can try this, `\b(?!2020|2021)(?<!\*|-)\d{4,5}(?!\*|-)\b`, https://regex101.com/r/rDd7ns/1. Not sure what you mean by duplicates

Comment: dublicatees it mean in this case `[1818] text 1818 text 1818` Result is 1818,1818,1818 expected result is  1818

Comment: Maybe you can create a function that can remove duplicate results from the matched regex